# Strange behaviour UIView height gets changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I encountered what I think is strange behaviour.
It would be nice if someone could clarify this.

In the viewDidLoad, initially I print height and width of UIView bounds, like this

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"WxH = %fx%f", self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);

}
```

which prints:  `WxH = 320.000000x548.000000`

Now, say I rotate the View controller to Landscape - and then back to portrait, and print the same height and width. Like this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

    // If the orientation is rotating to Portrait mode...
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(x))
    {
        NSLog(@"WxH = %fx%f", self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);


    }
    else // If the orientation is rotating to Landscape mode
    {  

    }

}
```

After this, every time I rotate, the above method prints `WxH = 320.000000x460.000000` (even if I am in Portrait mode as I was in the beginning when it printed 548)
Why has the height changed to 460? (Then it stays like this all the time)

Comment: I assume that you are testing on Retina 4 inch Display, can you confirm that the `UIView` has the `AutoResizing` property is set for full resize ?

Comment: @iphonic: When I click the XIB template that was created automatically for my view controller, all the 6 autoresizing lines are set to red. I also printed it like this: `NSLog(@"mask: %d", self.view.autoresizingMask);` and it prints 18

Comment: I guess that the superview autoresizes its subviews. Check the superview's properties in IB. And the size of your superview is not exaclty the same on the device as it is in IB.

Comment: BTW, willAnimateRotation ... is called before the rotation actually happens. So your NSLog is printed when the orientation is still portrait before it is rotated to landscape. (Of course after the device has been rotated physically).

Comment: @Hermann Klecker: I am using Simulator for 6.1. I created a ViewController with a XIB file. So I am directly working with the view of the view controller that was created by XCode. PS. You mean my NSLog is called when the orientation is still in Landscape mode?? This gets printed when I rotate to the landscape mode (if I add log to the else clause too): ` {{0, 0}, {480, 300}}`. If I rotate to the Portrait mode, this gets printed: {0, 0}, {320, 460}}. You never see 548 that was printed initially Anyway.

Comment: @iphonic: No, I was using just iPhone 6.1 simulator. No retina. When I switch to retina 4 in Hardware menu my app gets dissapeared and I have to reopen it. But then the log does not show at all... (Seems I am missing something).

Comment: Let me guess. In IB/Xcode you have the view displayed as if on an iPhone 5 (4") and you run an 3.5" simulator version. When it is loaded from XIB then it may have the size as defined in the XIB file. Howevert he actual screen of device is smaller, which you cannot enlarge programmatically. To me, 460 (which is 480 in total minus 20 for the status bar) is perfectly ok on a pre iPhone 5 device.

Answer (score 0):

Portrait iphone height Total 480 ,20 for the status bar remaining 460 for the self.view.

You can view the log in a better way as

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
```

It appears so because

The resolution is in points, not pixels. Your code should use points so it will run on any device--retina or non-retina. (To clarify--on a retina display, each screen pixel is 0.5x0.5 points, on non retina, the pixels are twice that size, 1x1 points)

Comment: Yes but why is it 548 initially as I mentioned?

Comment: did you build the xib for iphone 5 ??

Comment: I understand retina vs non retina concept but how does it explain my problem?

Comment: what is your view height in xib??

Comment: In the XIB it seems to be 548.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting/setting bounds/size in ViewDidLoad, perform the codes in ViewWillAppear.

This is not a "technical" answer, but it did the job for me.

Comment: it seems to do the trick, see what I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882199/view-height-problems-continued

Comment: Added an answer to the question.
Check there.

And accept this answer if it works the way you desired it to.