# View height problems (continued)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is in continuation to the problem I had here(which is still unresolved): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880148/strange-behaviour-uiview-height-gets-changed)

But this may help understand what is the problem.
I created just a simple test project ('Empty Application') and added a view controller with a XIB file (check box: 'With XIB file for user interface' selected). Code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"didLoad: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"didAppear: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));

}
```

This is the output:

```
2013-07-26 17:05:28.502 testtest[5926:c07] didLoad: {{0, 0}, {320, 548}}
2013-07-26 17:05:28.506 testtest[5926:c07] didAppear: {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
```

How come they are different?

(ps. I am testing on 6.1 simulator)

Comment: Your view will be resized when it is actually inserted into the view hierarchy. This is affected by navigation bars, status bar, toolbars, tab bars, whatever. So the size it has in Interface Builder (and which is loaded in viewDidLoad) will differ at runtime depending on the context.

Comment: @Mike Weller: does this mean I can't rely on dimensions such as self.bounds in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: That's exactly right. When viewDidLoad is called, your view controller's view hasn't actually been inserted into the view hierarchy. `viewWillAppear:` is a better place, and better still is to do all your layout code in a UIView subclass.

Comment: @Mike Weller: Imagine I just have some custom UIView subclass. And I want to position it on the view of my ViewController - where should I put code for that?

Answer (score 3):

When the `viewDidLoad` method is called, your view controller has only just been loaded from your storyboard or XIB, and so the view dimensions are equal to those that you have in the XIB (those looks like iPhone 5 height dimensions).

Later, when `viewDidAppear:` is called, the view has already appeared on the screen, so it has been resized appropriately to actually fit on the screen, so its dimensions may be different to those in your storyboard, and consequently different to those that are set when the view is loaded.

In your case, it looks like your storyboard or XIB file is set to iPhone 5 screen size (548 = 1136/2 - status bar), and you are testing in a pre-iPhone 5 simulator or device with a 480x320 point screen, so the view gets resized down to 460 points high to fit on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This could have perfect sense.

`ViewDidLoad` is called lazily when first access of `controller.view`, so by that time the frame is not set yet. This means that you can not rely on the frame/bounds sizes at this point because it will only contain a default value (although in many cases it will be correct).
In `ViewDidAppear`, the frame is usually set, although if your parent controller is setting any animation you could also have a temporal frame state instead of the final one, but it is not usual as by convention this method is called when the view is already displayed.

For example, if you are loading the view from an IB file, the frame you will get in the `viewDidLoad` is the one you have in the IB file, but maybe the final size for your view is smaller/bigger, and then you will get another one in your `viewDidAppear`.

Instead of that, **you should create all your elements resizable** (use Spring&Struts, AutoLayout or any other similar alternative) so they will be properly displayed when the frame is set.

Comment: Thanks for reponse, the view of my Vcontroller is resizable as you can see from here: http://postimg.org/image/gx4skl12v/

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. The view does not have the proper frame on viewDidLoad. That is all. What I suggested is to do it resizable, but not only the main view but the subviews, so no matter what size the view uses, the elements will be shown correctly. Your screenshot is about the mainview, which will usually be resized anyway, no matter the autoresizing properties.

Answer (score 0):

> When a `ViewController` presents its view, it normally shrinks that
>   view so that its frame does not overlap the device’s status bar.

So when you `NSLog` in `viewDidLoad`, the View i not yet loaded so `ViewController` has not shrinked the frame yet but in `viewDidAppear` , it has done the resizing.
There is a property in `UIViewController`
`wantsFullScreenLayout`

> Setting this property to YES causes the view controller to size its
>   view so that it fills the entire screen, including the area under the
>   status bar. (Of course, for this to happen, the window hosting the
>   view controller must itself be sized to fill the entire screen,
>   including the area underneath the status bar.) You would typically set
>   this property to YES in cases where you have a translucent status bar
>   and want your view’s content to be visible behind that view.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, ViewDidLoad will set the bounds for your application as defined, in the RootViewController/XIB-file for root view, or maybe the AppDelegate.

If you define the applications bounds there (not sure in which one of these), ViewDidLoad functions in the entire app, will initially, set the height according to that.

Once the View is loaded, and ready to 'appear', actual bounds may be requested.
Hence it is advised to request bounds/sizes in the ViewWillAppear/ViewDidAppear methods.

Answer (score 0):

`-viewDidLoad` is called the first time `viewController.view` is called. It is called before the view is returned. This has a very important implication. In order for the view to be shown or sized, it needs to be added to the window or some other view.

How does this happen? It looks something like `[window addSubview:viewController.view]`.

So, the fully loaded view is needed before it can be placed into the view hierarchy. This places limitations on `self.view` when used within `-viewDidLoad`.

1. `self.view.superview` and `self.view.window` will always be `nil`.
2. `self.view` is not yet sized to fit into `self.view.superview`.

With this understanding, you can see how `self.view` cannot know it's final size when `-viewDidLoad` is called.

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to apply a custom layout to a view's subviews, you may want to consider subclassing `UIView` and using `-[UIView layoutSubviews]`.

Barring that, are you having trouble with `-viewWillAppear:` instead of `-viewDidAppear:`? `-viewWillAppear:` is called before the view is displayed, so you won't have odd visual effects when you resize the view.

Comment: Which again means we can't rely much on bounds and such coordinates in `viewDidLoad`. So if some UI arrangements are needed, should one do it in `viwDidAppear`?

Comment: Imagine I just have one UIView which has three subviews: UIButton, UIButton, and UITextField - why do I have to care with subclassing?

Comment: Or let's put it in a different way. Just imagine I have some custom UIView subclass which I want to position on my ViewController's view. Where do I write the code to put it?