# Advice on how to use a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I have some app (from book) which looks like this:

[image]

You can see the image is cropped. I want to have a UIScrollView
which allows to scroll up and also see the whole picture.

This is how my app looks in interface builder.

[image]

What do you suggest where should I add ScrollView (as which subview etc.) to achieve what I need? (I guess I will need some intermediary UIView?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I usually do for fixed contents:

1. In IB create your view with a `UIScrollView` at your desired size and position connected to a `scrollView` outlet.
2. Also in IB create the view for the contents (bigger than the scroll view). Connect this to a `UIView` outlet called `contentView`.
3. In `viewDidLoad` do this:

   ```
   // Put the content view into the scroll view
   [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
   self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
   ```

If you want dynamic contents then programatically lay them out in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and set the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`.

Comment: Look what happens if I have such code:

`
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
     UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    
    [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
    
    [scrollView addSubview: mainView];
    
    [scrollView setContentSize:[mainView bounds].size];
    
      
}`

here is the screenshot of what I get with above code: http://postimg.org/image/5gumcich9/

`mainView` is an intermediary view - with blue bckgnd. You can see it overlaps with the UIToolbar...

Comment: That's because you're setting its frame to the full view bounds. Instead set the scroll view frame to the correct size (minus the toolbar) or preferably, do it in IB. Also on another note - you should not create views in `viewDidAppear`, do it in Interface Builder (IB) or in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: jhabbot: you say: "you should not create views in viewDidAppear" -- why??? I was avoiding viewDidLoad due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882199/view-height-problems-continued. Anyway, as you said I created the ScrollView in IB with right frame now (it was easier) and it seems to work ok - also that I put the code in viewDidLoad

Comment: Because `viewDidAppear` is called every time the view appears (for example when showing again after going back to it from a navigation, or unlock the screen, or dismiss a modal dialogue). So if you keep adding views there you will have lots of them.

Comment: hm... I see. Also one thing. Previously as my app was initially as you can see on the screenshot, when user clicked the TextField and keyboard would appear - and if user clicked outside that keyboard say on the area of my main `Control` I had implemented `resignFirstResponder` in `textFieldShouldReturn` (to make keyboard disappear). But now of course it does not work anymore because if user clicks outside the keyboard she clicks on the `mainView` -- what can I do in such a case?

Comment: That should probably be a different question

Answer (score 0):

Add the UIScrollView as a direct child of Control, and then put everything else inside the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UIScrollView` as first child of your main View and put all of your controls *`(UITextView, UILabel,...etc )`* as sub view of UIScrollView.

And use `UIScrollView` property [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) for set your visible area.

[For more information read this tutorial.](http://redartisan.com/2010/5/23/scrolling-with-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the UIScrollView directly under Control, then everything else, besides the toolbar should go into it.

What I usually do in these cases is set the scrollView to the size so all content fits, add the content, then resize the scrollview so it only occupies as much of the screen you want.